# How to insert multiple values to a node in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

For my current assignment I have to insert data from a file(which I already have uploaded (I DO NOT NEED HELP WITH THAT PART), but what I do not fully understand is how to assign this data to separate nodes.

```
 411048 2015 1 9.58
 411048 2015 3 14.82
 411048 2016 4 20.51
 411048 2016 1 10.99
 411000 1973 1 0.54
 411048 2016 3 18.40
 411048 2016 5 -99.99
```

That is the formatting of our information and corresponds to Location | Year | month | temperature
I understand how to input different nodes into a linked list using the head next and tail, but what I do not understand is how to assign each row of data to
a location, year, month and temperature to one node.

```
//skeletal function for this

void insert(std::string location, int year, int month, double temperature);
```

Any help is very appreciated, and if anyone trying to help would like, I can uploaded to skeletal code for my linkedlist.h/.cpp and my node.h/cpp

ALSO if a part of my question is unclear please let me know so I can try to clarify what it is I am asking.
Thanks.

Comment: review what a  'class' is.   Each node does not have 1 piece of data, but instead has 1 instance of the class.    Now figure out how to read the line into a class instance.  It sounds like you might know what it means to insert an element (a class instance) into a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some kind of input file stream (call it `ifs`), the easiest way to do what you're looking for is something like

```
std::string location;
int year;
int month;
double temperature;

while (ifs >> location >> year >> month >> temperature) {
  // actions
}
```

Comment: True. And within the loop simply iterate through nodes in your linked list and assign the values to the node